# Is it possible to customize NUnit XML output?

Tags: nunit

I'm looking at NUnit XML output right now and wonder if it's possible to generate the output **for failures only**.

I mean, if a test passes OK, no XML output gets generated for it at all.

XSLT is not an option here. **I don't want XML output for passed tests at all**: if I don't need the details about the passed tests, I don't want the system to spend time generating those details.*

The idea is, XML output tend to be quite large if you have a lot of tests, but 80% of the time you're after failures anyway. For such cases, I'd like to run my tests in such a way that only information on failures get generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question to the NUnit [Google Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) group, and Charlie Poole [confirmed](http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_frm/thread/5926e398cc970aca) that there's no such option.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify an XSLT file when you run the NUnit [console runner](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5) to customise the generated file:

```
nunit-console /transform:failures.xslt nunit.tests.dll
```

The default XML file is generated using [this XSLT file](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.2.5/files/Summary.xslt) which can be easily modified to report only failures.

Comment: Well, I mean I don't want any output for passed tests at all. If I don't need the details about the passed tests, I don't want the system to spend time generating those details.

Comment: Thanks Keith - we've been looking for a way to control the format of the file and your answer does exactly what we needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee if it works, but possibly you can write your own addin to achieve what you want.

If you hook into the extension point "EventListeners" with your addin, your method TestFinished(TestResult tr) which you'll have to implement will get called whenever a test is finished. Just readout the result and set the property WriteResultEntry to true only for failed tests.

Well, I'm not sure if Charlie has implemented the latter property, but if not, your addin could still create your own NUnit resultfile just for the failed tests.

```
/// <summary>
/// Test finished.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="result">The result.</param>
public void TestFinished(TestResult result)
{
   if (!result.IsFailure)
   {
      result.WriteResultEntry = false;
   }
}
```

If there's no such property WriteResultEntry, ask Charlie to implement it or create your own result report by only writing output when *result.IsFailure* is true.