# How not to display stack-trace in nUnit 2.6.4 xml results?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, nunit

I have a nunit test dll that I am running with the console runner, and that has a lot of failing tests with exceptions. The resulting xml file is too large and I think it will be a good idea to avoid writing the stack-trace in the xml output, since in my case it is not at all useful to display, and only write the exception message.

However, this is proving to be a lot more difficult than I expected.
I saw these two links, [where to find the xsd file that nunit uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878018/xsd-for-the-xml-file-that-nunit-uses) and [how to customize the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222203/is-it-possible-to-customize-nunit-xml-output), but in 2.6.4 the `/transform` option on the console appears to be deprecated, sigh.

I am not sure how to change the [files](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/files/) in my nUnit installation directory, will this affect the output? If anybody has managed to change the xml results output of nUnit, can they please point me in the right direction?

Comment: AFAICT you can't change the format of the xml output. Ths xslt is for screen representation only, not for file output. If the file is too large, maybe you could post process it, maybe through a PowerShell script. But why a large file is a stopping problem, in the first place?

Comment: Err... Why don't you fix those tests? Nunit tests which don't pass are kind of useless (because you don't even notice when they suddenly fail for some other reasons or if the number of failing tests changes)

Comment: The large file is a problem because the nUnit results are being displayed on the web by a continuous integration tool which struggles when the file is large. The short answer to why I don't fix the tests is that it's not my code which is being tested. I think the question was specific enough, I'm not looking for unit testing advice here.

Comment: NUnit 2.6.7 is the latest release of NUnit in the 2.6.x line.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look possible with nunit as it stands. Had a look around after you mentioned its being used by another tool.

Found [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/eMt7m1Wf5bE) on the nunit discussion board. It says the following:

As you probably know already, NUnit does not have any built-in way to 
customize the content of the XML file. We will work on that for NUnit 
3.0, but for NUnit 2.x, it would be necessary to build a modified copy 
of NUnit.

> The XML result file is created by the XmlResultWriter class, which is 
>   part of the nunit.util assembly. See 
>   http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nunit-core/nunitv2/trunk/view/head:/src/ClientUtilities/util/XmlResultWriter.cs